# "Report" button in RIDE.py becomes inactive after the first run

Tags: selenium, robotframework

After running a script when we make some changes and run it again the "Report" button at the top becomes inactive and the console remains blank.

[image]

Anyone facing this issue?

It only works if we clear cache memory after every run. I don't think it is an idle solution. Please share if anyone was a better solution.

Comment: This is one out of many annoying bugs in RIDE. This can't really be avoided and, from my experience, the cause seems to be quite random. Best you can do is keeping the log/report opened in a side browser tab and refresh after executions to get the updated version.

Comment: I think that there are these conditions to reproduce the bug:
1 - The operating system is Windows
2 - Test is using Selenium2Library

@Venv says it happens randomly. Is that your case too, Sudeep Sen?

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this when i.e. the IEDriver.exe process is still running after the test stops.

Closing this process is then sufficient to enable the buttons (after next run).

A teardown closing all browsers should prevent this from happening.

Comment: While this may be one cause, as stated in my comment to the question, there are multiple reasons why this bug can occur. The underlying issue is mainly stability issues in RIDE itself, which causes this kind of bug in different, unrelated scenarios.